# Import Word documents into SharePoint 2010 as publishing pages

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page, office-integration, word

Is it possible to import Word 2010 documents that contain images and text into  SharePoint 2010 publishing pages? We have a bunch of How-To documents with text and images and we want to automate turning these into pages, and merging some of them into single pages. Anyone know of a solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have never tried myself, I know you can leverage SharePoint's documnet conversion service to convert docx files into web pages.

First, you must enable the service. You may follow [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770227.aspx) link.

You can also create your own document converter. You can get started here: [SharePoint Server 2010 Document Converter Development Overview (ECM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms544523.aspx)

Also, there may be a few ISVs who may have already have extended this feature and provide much richer conversion service. For instance, [this](http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-office-to-pdf-conversion.aspx)